# How to keep structure of text after feeding it to a pipeline for NER

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize, huggingface-transformers, named-entity-recognition

I've build an NER (named entity recognition) model, based on a HuggingFace existing model and that I fine-tuned to recognize my custom entities. The text I want to run my model on is in a `txt` file.

The code of how I use the model:

```py
from transformers import pipeline

# loading the fine-tuned model
ner_pipeline =  pipeline('token-classification', model="./my-model.model/", tokenizer="./my-model.model/", ignore_labels=[])

with open(my_file, 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
  joined_lines = ' '.join(lines)

  result = ner_pipeline(joined_lines, aggregation_strategy='first')
  text = ""
      
  for group in result:
     if group["entity_group"] != 'O':
        # substitute the entity with its tag
        text += group["entity_group"]+ " "
     else:
        text += group["word"] + " "
```

Basically what I do is substituting the entities recognized with the entity tag, and leave the rest of the text as is.

With my code, the final `text` is filled with the content exactly as I want it, but the structure is lost. While doing `' '.join(lines)` I'm basically throwing away the `\n`s inside the text, that however I would like to keep in my reconstructed text.

I've tried feeding the pipeline with single sentences (each of the `f.readlines()`) end not the full joined text, but the results are far worse. The model works a lot better predicting on the whole text.

Does anyone knows a way how I could keep or retrieve the structure of the original text? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `group`s have a `start` and `end` index that tell you which part of the input string each label corresponds to. I.e., you can pass the text *as a whole*, with the newlines intact (`ner_pipeline(f.read(), ...)`) and subsequently replace substrings.

Here's a working, minimal reproducible example. The only thing to note here is that we replace from right to left (`result[::-1]`) so we don't mess up the indices of subsequent labels by changing the length of the string when replacing.

```py
from nltk.corpus import brown # for example data
from transformers import pipeline

ner_pipeline =  pipeline('token-classification')

# equivalent to f.read()
text = '\n'.join(' '.join(sent) for sent in brown.sents()[:100])

result = ner_pipeline(lines_joined, aggregation_strategy='first')

def replace_at(label, start, end, txt):
    """Replace substring of txt from start to end with label"""
    return ''.join((txt[:start], label, txt[end:]))

# Substitution
for group in result[::-1]:
    ent = group["entity_group"]
    if ent != 'ORG': # for testing since there's no 'O' in the default model
        text = replace_at(ent, group['start'], group['end'], text)

sentences = text.split('\n')
```

Example input/output (first line):

```py
"The Fulton County Grand Jury said Friday an investigation of Atlanta's recent primary election produced `` no evidence '' that any irregularities took place ."
```

After processing:

```py
"The Fulton County Grand Jury said Friday an investigation of LOC's recent primary election produced `` no evidence '' that any irregularities took place ."
                                                              ^^^
```